# Java and Hadoop apparently not properly installed

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop, setting up my environment for the first time ever in Ubuntu 18.10

I downloaded `jdk-8u101-linux-i586.tar.gz`, `jre-8u101-linux-i586.tar.gz` and `hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz and extracted them respectively with this command in my custom locations.

```
tar -xvf jdk-8u101-linux-i586.tar.gz
tar -xvf jre-8u101-linux-i586.tar.gz
tar -xvf hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz
```

I then updated ~/.bashrc file by appending the following information using `gedit`-

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hduser/HadoopPOC/hadoop-2.7.3
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

# Set JAVA_HOME

export JAVA_HOME=/home/hduser/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I then ran `source .bashrc` command and then logged out of my account and logged back in.

But I cannot determine if Java and Hadoop have been properly installed. I get these errors-

```
hduser@hduser-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin$ java -version
bash: /home/hduser/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java: No such file or directory

hduser@hduser-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin$ hadoop version
/home/hduser/HadoopPOC/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop: line 166: /home/hduser/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I did `ls` on $JAVA_HOME/bin and noticed that `java` exists.

[image]

Comment: Is the java command in /home/hadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin?
Given the variables you specified above, that is where your system will look for it. what does ls -l /home/hadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin show you?

Comment: you are right. The actual path is /home/hduser/HadoopPOC/.........

Comment: But I get another error msg now... 

`hduser@hduser-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin$ java -version

bash: /home/hduser/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Comment: I'll transfer my question to the answer, could you accept it please?

Comment: okay.. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Is the java command in `/home/hadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin`?

Given the variables you specified above, that is where your system will look for it.
What does `ls -l /home/hadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin` show you?

As you indicated in the Q&A, the paths were incorrect.

Re the new question, it has hard to tell without seeing the details. Probably it is a similar issue - the path specified (`/home/hduser/HadoopPOC/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java`) does not exist.

Comment: Thanks @GMc I have updated the question with latest data, hope there is all info you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed a 32-bit java in a 64-bit machine, which is why it didn't work. Now I've installed a 64-bit jdk and it recognises `java -version`

Comment: Curious, 32 bit code should run in a 64 bit O.S. I've had to do this on a few occasions. Of course the reverse won't work - 64 bit code will not run on a 32 bit system. However, glad it worked out for you.